# html form hidding a particular column

Tags: html

I have  a HTMl Form with table data as :

```
Name
Place 
ID
```

for the user Name, Place only should be displayed. But ID should not be displayed.
My intention is on the UI I do not want the user to see the ID. but in the back ground that ID should be there . so that when he updates and send  the form using submit server can  get the information the way it want.

so example: actual table data

```
Greg xxx 11111
Adam yyy  11112
```

to the user it should display as

```
Greg xxx 
Adam yyy
```

I tried to use the `hidden` keyword and it did not work

```
  <td>   
    <input readonly="hidden" type="text" name="id" id="mytext" size="9" value="1111 />    </td>
  <td>   
    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="name" id="mytext" size="9" value="Greg" /> 
  </td>
  <td>  
    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="location" id="mytext1" size="25" value="xxxx" /> 
  </td>
```

I missed to tell that I also have  that is the problem alignment is messed up and I can get the values for only 1 element displayed

Comment: How'd you use `the "hidden"` keyword?

Comment: Instead of Type="text" you should use type="hidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="mytext" size="9" value="111" />` for ID

Comment: I missed to tell that I also have <th> that is the problem alignment is messed up and I can get the values for only 1 element displayed

Comment: I think td is fine the question is for th. the header I have only 2 colums name and location,

Comment: There're many ways to hide it. One of them is to assign class to it and use CSS to hide it. For example, `.hide { display: none; }` so that that column will be hidden to the user

Answer (score 2):

The readonly attribute is only for making the element editable or not.

Use `type="hidden"` instead.

[Input element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), [Input types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#InputType)

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="hidden"`. And you might not want to put it into a separate `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  display:none;
}
table tr th:nth-child(1) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: this does not support in CSS2

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn I don't see OP saying anything about CSS2.